# Json Merge an id to a url

Tags: javascript, json, jira

Good morning everybody,

i'm working on a Slack Workflow and i exported the .json file to work on it manually.

In a step of the workflow, it opens a ticket on Jira and returns the Issue Key with this form:

```js
"id": "d9332296-a027-4b51-a52b-d8d69f131374==issueKey"
```

I need to automatically add that ID to an url, i tried to pass it through % encoding but it doesn't work.

This is the code related to the specific action:

```
[
    {
        "id": "**d9332296-a027-4b51-a52b-d8d69f131374==issueKey**",
        "type": "workflowtoken",
        "property": "",
        "data_type": "text"
    },
    {
        "text": "\n\nLink to the issue: ",
        "type": "text"
    },
    {
        "url": "https://test.slack.com/channels/**%7B%7Bd9332296-a027-4b51-a52b-d8d69f131374%3D%3DissueKey%7D%7D**",
        "text": "LINK",
        "type": "link"
    }
]
```

Do you know any easy way to store the value and pass it (like concatenate it with the url) or any other valid way to reach my goal?

Thank you very much,
P.

I tried to pass a json ID  through % encoding to the url but it doesn't work.

Comment: How do you generate this data? Can you edit the url there?

Comment: This is part of the .json file of the Workflow builder and yes i can edit all the file!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to understand the context but the simplest way is to define some placeholder like `JIRA_ISSUE_KEY` and then replace it on every property that should get this issue key.

```js
const dataObject = {
  "id": "**d9332296-a027-4b51-a52b-d8d69f131374==JIRA_ISSUE_KEY",
  "type": "workflowtoken",
  "property": "",
  "data_type": "text"
}

const injectVariables = (data, property, value) => {
  const result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)); // silly copy
  for(const key of Object.keys(result)){
    if(result.hasOwnProperty(key)){
      result[key] = result[key].replace(property, value);
    }
  }
  return result;
};

const injectedData = injectVariables(dataObject, 'JIRA_ISSUE_KEY', 'project-123');
console.log(injectedData);
```